# Is there a linux command to find out how many SSDs my laptop can support?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, laptop, ssd

**Background**: I'd like to benchmark some SSDs. I am thinking about doing this on my laptop. I would like to check if my laptop supports using multiple SSDs at the same time. I don't want to have to dismantle my laptop to find out, as I currently don't have the tools. I am using an HP Elitebook 8570w.

**Question**: Is there a linux command that tells how many slots for SSDs my laptop has?

**Attempt so far**: I've been looking at dmidecode. The command “dmidecode -t 8” seems to give info about sata connectors, and “dmidecode -t 9” seems to give info about PCI connectors, but I couldn't find info on how to interpret the output. It seems like I have 6 SATA connectors and 1 PCI connector, but I am not sure what's being used. Moreover, even if the motherboard has an available connector, is there any guarantee the laptop would have the physical space for the additional SSD?

“dmidecode -t 9” gives:

```
Handle 0x0020, DMI type 9, 13 bytes
System Slot Information
        Designation: PCI SLOT1
        Type: 32-bit PCI
        Current Usage: Available
        Length: Long
        ID: 1
        Characteristics:
                3.3 V is provided
                PME signal is supported
                SMBus signal is supported
```

“dmidecode -t 8” gives:

```
Handle 0x0019, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: Ctrl0Port0
        Internal Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
        External Reference Designator: Primary HDD Bay
        External Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
        Port Type: SATA

Handle 0x001A, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: Ctrl0Port5
        Internal Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
        External Reference Designator: Docking Station Upgrade Bay
        External Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
        Port Type: SATA

Handle 0x001B, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: Ctrl0Port4
        Internal Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
        External Reference Designator: eSATA
        External Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
        Port Type: SATA

Handle 0x001C, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: Ctrl0Port3
        Internal Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
        External Reference Designator: Docking Station eSATA
        External Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
        Port Type: SATA

Handle 0x001D, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: Ctrl0Port2
        Internal Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
        External Reference Designator: mSATA
        External Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
        Port Type: SATA

Handle 0x001E, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: Ctrl0Port1
        Internal Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
        External Reference Designator: Upgrade Bay
        External Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
        Port Type: SATA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to find information like that is simply to look in the manual or on the specifications of the laptop.  I did a quick google search and quickly found the answer.

"In addition, a secondary SSD could be installed in the optical bay (or the old hard drive could be installed there instead). Another tempting option is to use an mSATA SSD in combination with the hard drive or a Solid State Drive."

Basically, if you're testing 2.5" SSDs you can only fit one and a second in the optical bay with an adapter. This is generally not recommended since it usually has a slower SATA interface.

Your motherboard and chipset may support additional SATA drives but if you don't have a connector it is a moot point since you cannot add them anywhere.

Source:  http://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-HP-EliteBook-8570w-Notebook.83982.0.html

Comment: Thank you. I should have looked harder at the specs before asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a maximum of two disk drives on an EliteBook. The second drive is fitted in place of the DVD drive.